# Perfect group of exponent 3?

Tags: group-theory

**Question.** Is there a nontrivial group $G$ such that $[G,G]=G$ and $g^3=1$ for every $g\in G$?

All I could think of so far is the following.

- If such a group exists it must be infinitely generated due to the local finiteness of groups of exponent 3.
- Perfect groups of large enough prime exponent do exist, e.g. a [Tarski Monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group).

Comment: Why exponent three? Why not arbitrary exponent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $\exp\,G=3$. Then [the nilpotency class of $G$ is at most $3$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_three_implies_class_three_for_groups). Hence $[[[G,G],G],G]=1$. But if $G$ is a perfect group, then $G=[G,G]=[[G,G],G]=[[[G,G],G],G]=1$, an impossibility.

Comment: Easy and straightforward approach +1